# Trim FASTA headers with sed

Tags: awk, sed, fasta

I have a reference genome containing the following headers (lines starting with >) that I would like to be renamed to simply the digit/letter of the chromosomes. I would like a sed statement to do this systematic replacement, but I am new to sed. Elsewhere in the file are additional headers that should be unchanged, and the genetic sequences between the headers should remain unchanged.

```
>ST078050.1 Ovis aries is a sheep chromosome 1, whole genome shotgun sequence
>ST078051.1 Ovis aries is a sheep chromosome 2, whole genome shotgun sequence
>ST078052.1 Ovis aries is a sheep chromosome 3, whole genome shotgun sequence
>ST078053.1 Ovis aries is a sheep chromosome 4, whole genome shotgun sequence
>ST078054.1 Ovis aries is a sheep chromosome 5, whole genome shotgun sequence
>ST078055.1 Ovis aries is a sheep chromosome 6, whole genome shotgun sequence
>ST078056.1 Ovis aries is a sheep chromosome 7, whole genome shotgun sequence
>ST078057.1 Ovis aries is a sheep chromosome 8, whole genome shotgun sequence
>ST078058.1 Ovis aries is a sheep chromosome 9, whole genome shotgun sequence
>ST078059.1 Ovis aries is a sheep chromosome 10, whole genome shotgun sequence
>ST078079.1 Ovis aries is a sheep chromosome X, whole genome shotgun sequence
>ST078080.1 Ovis aries is a sheep chromosome Y, whole genome shotgun sequence
```

Output should be:

```
>1
>2
>3
>4
>5
>6
>7
>8
>9
>10
>X
>Y
```

I tried the following, but it's not right.

```
sed 's/^.*\(chromosome.*,\).*$/\1/' file
```

Thank you!

Comment: This might help: `awk '{print ">" substr($1, 1, length($1)-1)}' FPAT='[^ ]+,' file`

Comment: So, `>`are part of the file contents? I [have updated my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66067595/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the above are just some headers of actual fasta files, and the remaining sequence is still in the files, then the following solutions will do the job:

```
$ sed '/^>/{s/,.*//;s/^.* />/}' file.fasta
$ awk '/^>/{sub(/,.*$/,"");$0=">"$NF}1' file.fasta
```

Both methods do exactly the same. In the line that starts with a `>`, remove the string starting with a `,` till the end and replace everything upto the last space with a `>`. The latter is done in awk by simple calling the last field.

Comment: This is great! It works. Even for the other header lines, it shortens them in an informative way by the contig number.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/chromosome [^,]*/){
  print substr($0,1,1) substr($0,RSTART+11,RLENGTH-11)
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                              ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/chromosome [^,]*/){      ##Using match function to match regex chromosome till comma comes here.
  print substr($0,1,1) substr($0,RSTART+11,RLENGTH-11)
                                   ##Printing sub string to print 1st character then substring of matched regex removing chromosome from it.
}
' Input_file                       ##Mentioning Input_file here.
```

Once you are happy with results shown above command try following command to save output into Input_file itself.

```
awk '
match($0,/chromosome [^,]*/){
  print substr($0,1,1) substr($0,RSTART+11,RLENGTH-11)
}
'  Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

Comment: Yes, this works and gives the right output, but does it replace the lines in the file?

Comment: @HLudwig, sure for saving output into Input_file itself please append ` > temp && mv temp Input_file` at last of my code, let me edit my answer too now, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed, regex, and back-reference:

```
sed -E 's/(.).* ([^ ]+),.*/\1\2/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

another `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/chromosome/s/^>.* (.+),.*/>\1/' file

>1
>2
>3
>4
>5
>6
>7
>8
>9
>10
>X
>Y
```

for the lines containing chromosome find the chars before the comma and replace the record with that token keeping the initial `>` sign.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sh
sed -E 's/^>.*chromosome ([[:alnum:]]+),.*$/>\1/' file > newfile
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/K5SkfK).

*Details*

- `-E` - enables POSIX ERE syntax
- `^>.*chromosome ([[:alnum:]]+),.*$` - find start of string (`^`), then `>`, any text (`.*`), `chromosome` word, a space, then captures into Group 1 any one or more alphanumeric chars, then matches a comma and the rest of the string
- `>\1` - replaces the matched line (here, it is a line) with the `>` and the contents of Group 1.

If you need to replace the same file contents use

```sh
sed -i -E 's/^>.*chromosome ([[:alnum:]]+),.*$/>\1/' file                   # GNU sed
sed -i '' -E 's/^>.*chromosome ([[:alnum:]]+),.*$/>\1/' file                # FreeBSD sed
sed 's/^>.*chromosome \([[:alnum:]]*\),.*$/>\1/' file > tmp && mv tmp file  # any sed, POSIX BRE syntax
```